# $\sigma(\overline{z})=\overline{\sigma(z)}$ with $\sigma$ $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to prove the following:

For fields $\mathbb{Q}\subset F \subset \mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$, with $\xi_n$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity, prove that $\sigma(\overline{z})=\overline{\sigma(z)}$ for every  $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $F$ and $z\in F$. (The bar indicates complex conjugation).

My issue with this problem is the fact that I am being asked to prove this for a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ and not for $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ itself.

This is what I would do if $F$ were $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$:

Since there is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ made of powers of $\xi_n$, I think it is enough to prove that $\sigma(\overline{\xi_n})=\overline{\sigma(\xi_n)}$. Since $\xi_n^n=1$, we have $1=|\xi_n|=\xi_n\overline{\xi_n}$ and therefore $\xi_n^{-1}=\overline{\xi_n}$. It is also true that $\overline{\sigma(\xi_n)} = \sigma(\xi_n)^{-1}$ because $\sigma$ takes roots of $x^n-1$ to roots of $x^n-1$. Then $\sigma(\overline{\xi_n})=\sigma(\xi_n^{-1})=\sigma(\xi_n)^{-1}=\overline{\sigma(\xi_n)}$.

However, if $F$ is not equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$, I am concerned that this proof would not work because it may happen that $\xi_n$ is not even in $F$, so its image by $\sigma:F\rightarrow F$ would not be defined.

I would find it very helpful if someone could explain how I could fix my proof so that I can use it in this second case or maybe point out a different approach that would work in that situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This follows directly from the fact that the Galois group of a cyclotomic extension is abelian.

Comment: @Ihf How do you prove that conjugation is an automorphism? And how do you know that $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ is also abelian? I only know $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\xi)/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: $\sigma(\overline{z})$ doesn't make much sense if you don't know that $\overline{z}\in F$. Extend $\sigma$ to an automorphism $\sigma'$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\xi)$ then $\sigma'$ and the complex conjugaison commute. You don't need it here but we prove that $F/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois and abelian from the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.